# Web Method don't Read

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I make this the code when i press delete button delete specific row from database 
Delete function didn't read when i click the button only show Confirm message and don't make anything
[image]
this my `CS.aspx` code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Book_ID" HeaderText="Book_ID" HeaderStyle-Width="30" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Book_Name" HeaderText="Book_Name" HeaderStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Book_Author" HeaderText="Book_Author" HeaderStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Book_Description" HeaderText="Book_Description" HeaderStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="50">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfBook_ID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Book_ID") %>' />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("[id*=GridView1] [id*=lnkDelete]").click(function () {
                    if (confirm("Do you want to delete this Book?")) {
                        //Determine the GridView row within whose LinkButton was clicked.
                        var row = $(this).closest("tr");

                        //Look for the Hidden Field and fetch the Book_ID.
                        var book_ID = parseInt(row.find("[id*=hfBook_ID]").val());

                        //Make an AJAX call to server side and pass the fetched Book_ID.
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "CS.aspx/DeleteBook",
                            data: '{book_ID: ' + book_ID + '}',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (r) {
                                if (r.d) {
                                    //Remove the row from the GridView.
                                    row.remove();
                                    //If the GridView has no records then display no records message.
                                    if ($("[id*=GridView1] td").length == 0) {
                                        $("[id*=GridView1] tbody").append("<tr><td colspan = '4' align = 'center'>No records found.</td></tr>")
                                    }
                                    alert("Book record has been deleted.");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </form>
```

and this my delete function `CS.aspx.cs`

```
[WebMethod]
    public bool DeleteBook(int Book_ID)
    {

        using (con = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Book WHERE Book_ID = @Book_ID"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Book_ID", Book_ID);
                con.Open();
                int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                return rowsAffected > 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is the `DeleteBook()` function in server side doesn't work

Comment: Any errors in your javascript console or network tab in the browser?

Comment: You asked the exact same question yesterday. In it, I asked you to debug and tell us if the server side function was being retrieved and if there were any error messages. Then you create a new question today and don't include the information? That stuff is critical to include your question, because we're not sitting at your computer. You are.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't retrieve anything". The purpose of your function is to delete, not retrieve. **Is the method reached? How far does it get? Does it delete the row from the database, but not the UI?** You need to provide a lot more detail if you expect to receive help.

Comment: What @mason says, 'is your DeleteBook method hit'? What happens if you set a breakpoint within that method? And if so, what's the value of book_ID? 
It seems strange to me you use ID's in your jQuery selectors. Doesn't your grid render multiple rows? You can't use an ID more than once...

Comment: @Mr.White It's also strange to use string concatenation `string value = "DELETE FROM Book WHERE Book_ID =" + book_ID.ToString();` and parameters `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Book_ID", book_ID);` at the same time. It's clear Ahmed hasn't spent any time debugging this code.

Comment: Ha, ohw.... I hadn't even come that far reading....

Comment: @mason the method don't reached when i debug my code and didn't make any thing to database or UI when i put any id to the function to test it  the specific row id was deleted from the database and UI so my problem to pass the id  to the delete function

Comment: Can you show a piece of the rendered GridView? What's the outcome?

Comment: @mason sorry for that i forget to edit my code in the question can you see it now

Comment: See, now you're getting somewhere. Time to debug the JavaScript now that you've ruled out the server method as the current problem. I'd use your browser's debugging tools to step through the JavaScript and see what happens, and I'd probably remove that `return false` statement.

Comment: Sorry, I meant HTML output, we need to see some source code. If the problem is getting the ID into your ajax call, you have to show the complete HTML outcome of the GridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get your sample code working using a simple `<input>` field for the `book_ID` value. I had to fix a couple of issues though.

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" value="234" id="fld" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            if (confirm('Do you want to delete this Book?')) {
                var book_ID = parseInt($('#fld').val());
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "callservice.aspx/DeleteBook",
                    data: '{Book_ID:' + book_ID + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool DeleteBook(int Book_ID)
    {
        return Book_ID.Equals(234);
    }
```

- use POST as the type
- rename argument name Book_ID to match method parameter in CodeBehind
- make the `DeleteBook` method static